# Python - 25k requests json arror

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to make a JSON file with the ID's and Name's from all the grand exchange items (OS runescape). I do this by requesting every id and seeing if I get an answer. this part works but after a while (sometimes 20 and sometimes 140) I get an JSON error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\python.py", line 19, in <module>
    c = json.loads(r.text)
  File "c:\users\ricardo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "c:\users\ricardo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "c:\users\ricardo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I thought maybe just make an try catch and the ones that fail I could do myself but after the first one all next ones also fail so...

I'm kinda stranded and don't know how to fix this.

```
import requests 
import json
import time

data = {"itemdb":[]};
print(data)
fout = []

for i in range(25813):
try:
    x = str(i)
    r = requests.get('http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=' + x + '')

    t = r.text[:1]
    if(t == "<"):
        print("#"+ x +" none")
    else:
        c = json.loads(r.text)
        idx = c["item"]["id"];
        name = c["item"]["name"];

        obj = {"id":idx,"name":name}
        data['itemdb'].append(obj)
        print("#"+ x + " " + repr(obj) + "")

except ValueError:
    print("#" + x + " FAILED!!!!")
    fout.append(x)

print(fout)

f = open("items.json", "w")

f.write(repr(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to assume that the response (`r.text`) will contain a value. Based on the error you posted, however, it appears that is not always the case. The JSON decoder doesn't know how to decode `None`, so you should handle that case separately. Simply inspect the request once you get it back. If the return code of the response is an error, or if you get back no data at all, you should either skip that entry or retry it.

I'm guessing that the Runescape servers are detecting that you're hitting their service all at once and throttling you (which is likely why you consistently get errors after the first one). You will likely need to introduce some sleep calls (or something similar) to run these queries over time.

Comment: When I check every request with r.text the once that fail just say nothing